# Java MVC: Updating View using Observer pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing

In my application I have `View` that observes `Model` changes. `Controller` is responsible for handling events dispatched by `View` and updating `Model`.

For the sake of example, lets suppose I have two views. First, `InputView`, contains two `JSpinner` elements (`Spinner1` and `Spinner2`). Second, `ResultView`, contains `JLabel` with values from spinners. And as additional constraint, we want to have values of `Spinner2` be dependent on values of `Spinner1`. Lets say, that minimum value in `Spinner2` should be `2x` current value of `Spinner1`.

When we change value of `Spinner1` `Controller` receives `ChangeEvent` and updates `Model`. Since we also have to adjust value of `Spinner2` another `ChangeEvent` will be dispatched and `Model` will be updated second time. The problem with this schema is that with each `Model` update the observing `View` refreshes. So, in this example the `View` would refresh 3 or 4 times instead of one (`Spinner1` change, `Spinner2` minimum value change, `Spinner2` value change). This causes flickering.

How to I make sure the `View` updates only once when all changes are done?

Comment: please post an SSCCE, because I have not idea about flickering, there must be another recrusive issue in your code

Comment: By flickering I mean consequent refreshing of the view. If we use some sort of chart or anything more complex than just a label, multiple refreshes will be noticible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [gang-of-four book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) says:

"Who triggers the update? The subject and its observers rely on the notification mechanism to stay consistent. But what object actually calls Notify to trigger the update? Here are two options:

```
Have state-setting operations on Subject call Notify after they change the 
subject's state. The advantage of this approach is that clients don't have 
to remember to call Notify on the subject. The disadvantage is that several
consecutive operations will cause several consecutive updates, which may be
inefficient.

Make clients responsible for calling Notify at the right time. The advantage 
here is that the client can wait to trigger the update until after a series 
of state changes has been made, thereby avoiding needless intermediate updates.
The disadvantage is that clients have an added responsibility to trigger the 
update. That makes errors more likely, since clients might forget to call Notify.
```

the second option may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

The article [*Java SE Application Design With MVC: Issues With Application Design*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/mvc-136693.html#5) puts the problem in context and suggests using a property change "to check the incoming changed value of the model against the current value stored in the Swing component."

Answer (score 1):

So this is how observing is done:

```
label -> spinner 2 -> spinner 1
```

If I were you, I would set "types for changes". So in my controller I could be able to control how to notify my observers.

I can be more helpful if you post your code.

Comment: No, `label` observes `Model`. The panel with spinners also observes 'Model'. Each `spinner` dispatches `state changes` to `Controller` which modifies `Model`. At this point `InputView` updates value of dependant `spinner 2`, which trigers second wave of `Model` updates